# How can I use recursion to visually stack a basic block in Scheme?

Tags: recursion, stack, scheme

I am trying to use recursion to stack a basic block I created (y), x amount of times high.

```
(define stack-copies-of
(lambda (x y)
  (cond
    ((= x 0) 0)
    ((> x 0) (stack y y)
```

I didn't go any further because well... I'm stumped. I want the stack of blocks to appear on the screen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not using recursion. `stack-copies-of` is not `stack`. 
You need to look at basic list operations. Heres some that makes a list:

```
;; easiest version, looks most like the one you started with
(define (make-list num-elements)
  (if (zero? num-elements)
      '() ; the tail of the list is the empty list
      (cons '* (make-list (- num-elements 1)))))

;; tail recursive version using auxillary procedure
(define (make-list num-elements)
  ;; we define a local auxillary procedure to do the work
  (define (make-list-aux num-elements acc)
    (if (zero? n)
        acc ; return the produced list
        (make-list-aux (- n 1) 
                       (cons '* acc))))
  ;; fire it off
  (make-list-aux num-elements '()))

;; exactly the same as the previous, but with a named let
(define (make-list num-elements)
  ;; a named let can be called by name as a procedure, creating a loop
  (let make-list-aux ((num-elements num-elements)
                      (acc '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (make-list-aux (- n 1)
                       (cons '* acc)))))

(display (make-list 10)) ; print the result
```

I expect what you're after could be based on one of these except instead of '* you use your extra argument.

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is a stack you can define it and the related operations push, pop and one to display the stack.

```
(define stack '())

(define (push e)
  (set! stack (cons e stack)))

(define (pop)
  (let ((e (car stack)))
    (set! stack (cdr stack))
    e))

(define (display-stack)
  (for-each
   (lambda (e) (display e) (newline))
   stack))
```

the following is the recursive function to stack n times an element

```
(define (stack-ntimes n e)
    (when (> n 0)
      (push e)
      (stack-ntimes (- n 1) e)))
```